# expect is not defined in supertest-as-promised

Tags: node.js, mongoose, supertest-as-promised

When I used bellow code the error shown **expect is not defined** (inside of then )

Documentation [link](https://github.com/WhoopInc/supertest-as-promised#debugging)

```
it("should return error", function () {
  return request(app).get("/verify")
    .expect(200)
    .then(function (res) {
      return expect(res.body.error[0].message).to.equal("NEW_CODE_REQUIRED");
    });
});
```

how can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following process. Added a function to check expected error that return error if got unexpected value and this function called from `.expect()`

```
function checkErrorMessage(res) { // this function throw error if got unexpected result
   if(res.body.error[0].message === 'NEW_CODE_REQUIRED') {
     return false; // return false means no error (got expected result)
   } else {
     return true; // return true means return error (got unexpected result)
   }
}

it("should return error", function () {
  return request(app).get("/verify")
    .expect(200)
    .expect(checkErrorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of an oversight of the documentation not to mention that a standalone `expect` function isn't included in the package.

For that, you have to use a separate package, like [`chai`](https://github.com/chaijs/chai):

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
...
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep but can I solve it only using supertest-as-promised ?